# How to use log4j Logger in Android Testing project

Tags: android, unit-testing, logging, log4j

I am writing an Android Test Project for testing my application. I want to setup a logger for this project so that i can log test result into a log file(separate from the log file of application for which i am designing test). But i am not able to do so.I have tried this code to configure logger so far:

```
public class TestLogger extends MockApplication {

public static final Logger TESTLOG;

static {
    LogConfigurator config = new LogConfigurator();
    config.setFileName(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + <Directory path>+ "<logfilename>.txt");
    String filePattern = "%-5p [%F:%L] %d{ISO8601} %x - %m%n";
    config.setFilePattern(filePattern);
    config.setMaxFileSize(1024 * 1024 * 5);// Max file size 5MB
    config.setRootLevel(Level.INFO);
    config.setLevel("org.apache", Level.ERROR);
    config.setImmediateFlush(true);
    config.configure();
    TESTLOG = Logger.getLogger(TestLogger.class);
}

}
```

It throws Java.lang.ExceptionInInitailizerError for logger existing for my application which i am going to test. Is there any way to get rid of this problem.